# Azure cognitive search how to exactly match the field with AND operator

Tags: azure, full-text-search, azure-cognitive-search

I have some entities in `Azure Cognitive Search Index`. I would like to order my entities in the following way: the records that match criteria `<fieldName>: "value"` go first, and others(with other values and with nulls) go next, but also, I would like to search with `searchText` while ordering.

Suppose all records matched with `searchText`:

```
{
    ...,
    <fieldName>: "value",
    ...,
},
{
    ...,
    <fieldName>: "value",
    ...,
},
{
    ...,
    <fieldName>: "value <other trash>",
    ...,
},
{
    ...,
    fieldName: null,
    ...,
}
```

I'm using `Azure Cognitive Search REST` api with `Lucene syntax`. I figured out the following solution:

```
{
  "search": "(<searchKeyWord> AND <fieldName>: 'value') OR <searchKeyWord>"
  "queryType": "full",
  "searchMode": "all"
}
```

It works, but the results aren't matched exactly, among the result list I have `<fieldName>: 'value somethingelse', <fieldName>: 'value fff'`. But I want it to match exactly.

If we try to call

```
{
    "search": "<fieldName>: 'value'"
    "queryType": "full",
    "searchMode": "all"
}
```

it matches exactly because of some reason.

But if we put it like that:

```
{
    "search": "<searchKeyWord> AND <fieldName>: 'value'"
    "queryType": "full",
    "searchMode": "all"
}
```

it doesn't match exactly and starts returning `<fieldName>: 'value somethingelse', <fieldName>: 'value fff'`. Even with `searchMode: all`.
I also tried to use `OR` operator instead of `AND`. And it seems like working exactly in the same way, so what the point of `AND` operator?

Does anyone encounter such a behavior, could you please share how did you resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

what determine the order is the relevance, which is calculated by the TFxIDF formula. What you should do is try to inspect why a particular document that should not be on top, is on top.

Take a look at the debug sessions:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-debug-session

Comment: probably it's not an issue with order, it's an issue with matching the string with operator AND.
Cause the results with `<fieldName>: 'value'` are matched exactly, but with `<searchKeyWord> AND <fieldName>: 'value'` are not matched exactly, it looks like operator `AND ` is treated like operator `OR`. And I would like it to be matched exactly.